# NGINX redirect subdomain to sub directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I know this must have been answered a million times but I can't seem to get it to work

I would like to redirect a subdomain to a subdirectory.

I am currently using

```
server {
server_name sub.domain.com;
rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/sub-directory permanent;
}
```

If I navigate to sub.domain.com I am redirected to http://www.domain.com

---

**EDIT**

Here's my full config.  I have changed the actual domains and sub directories

```
server {
server_name forum.domain.com;
rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/forum permanent;
}

server {
# Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
listen xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;


server_name domain.com www.domain.com;


# Path to the files in which you wish to
# store your access and error logs.
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

root /usr/share/nginx/www;

location /wordpress-blog {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress-blog/index.php?args;
}

#root is a magento ecommerce install
location / {
    index index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}


    #this part makes all pretty urls work for my simple machines forum
location /forum/
{

    index index.php index.html;

    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
            # Rules for: profiles
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/profile/([^/]+)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=profile;user=$1" last;

            # Rules for: actions
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(activate|admin|ads|announce|attachapprove|ban|boardrecount|buddy|calendar|clock)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(collapse|convertentities|coppa|credits|deletemsg|detailedversion|display|dlattach|editpoll|editpoll2)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(emailuser|featuresettings|findmember|groups|help|helpadmin|im|jseditor|jsmodify)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(jsoption|lock|lockvoting|login|login2|logout|manageboards|managecalendar|managesearch|manageattachments|maintain|markasread|mascot)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(membergroups|mergetopics|mlist|moderate|modifycat|modifykarma|movetopic|movetopic2|news|notify)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(notifyboard|optimizetables|openidreturn|packages|permissions|pm|post|postsettings|post2|printpage|profile|quotefast)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(quickmod|quickmod2|recent|regcenter|register|register2|reminder|removepoll|removetopic2)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(repairboards|reporttm|requestmembers|restoretopic|reports|search|search2|sendtopic|serversettings|smileys|smstats|suggest)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(spellcheck|splittopics|stats|sticky|theme|trackip|about:mozilla|about:unknown)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(unread|unreadreplies|verificationcode|viewErrorLog|viewmembers|viewprofile|vote|viewquery|viewsmfile|who)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/(\.xml|xmlhttp)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;

            # Rules for: boards
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;board=$1.0" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2" last;

            # Rules for: topics
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.0" last;
            rewrite ^/burton-snowboard-forum/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*|msg[0-9]*|new)/?$ "/burton-snowboard-forum/index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.$3" last;

            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?params=$1 last;
    }
}

#Magento configurations

# Deny access to specific directories no one
# in particular needs access to anyways.
location /app/ { deny all; }
location /includes/ { deny all; }
location /lib/ { deny all; }
location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
location /var/ { deny all; }

# Allow only those who have a login name and password
# to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.
location /var/export/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    autoindex on;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files
# such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
location ~ /\. {
     deny all;
     access_log off;
     log_not_found off;
}

# This redirect is added so to use Magentos
# common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

# Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
# to their relevant handler.
location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

# Handle the exectution of .php files.
location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite / /index.php last;
    }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE btn;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Comment: It works. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Post your full config.

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    return 301 http://www.domain.com/sub-directory$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not having any luck with this.  sub.domain.com loads the content that www.domain.com would load. I need it to go to www.domain.com/my-sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

I think some of what you're trying to do is being lost when you use the generic sub.domain.com - to specifically send the sub-domain to the directory of the same name you have 2 options:

Hard code each one

```
server {
  server_name sub1.domain.com;
  return 301 "http://domain.com/sub1${uri}";
}

server {
  server_name sub2.domain.com;
  return 301 "http://domain.com/sub2${uri}";
}
```

Or match with regular expressions (less efficient but easier)

```
server {
  server_name ~^(?<sub>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$; # will cause the sub-domain to be placed in $sub
  return 301 "http://domain.com/${sub}${uri}";
}
```

Note that $uri includes the leading slash which is different to Apache's mod_rewrite.

Comment: Please, do not use `rewrite` instead of simple [`return`](http://nginx.org/r/return).

Comment: What is this `_` in your `server_name`? btw, domain matching are always case insensitive. Losing request arguments isn't a good idea (replacing $uri with $request_uri should fix it).

Comment: The _ is a remnant of my older nginx configurations for catchall blocks. It isn't relevant here so I've removed it.

Comment: Both these provided solutions don't work for me.  sub.domain.com loads the content that www.domain.com would load.  I need it to go to www.domain.com/my-sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

This could just be done very simply with a rewrite ...

```
if ($host !~* ^www\.example\.com) {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Just make sure your "normal" `server` entry also listens for this domain name

```
server {

  # Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
  listen xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;

  server_name example.com www.example.com mysubdomain.example.com;

  location / {
    if ($host !~* ^www\.example\.com) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    }
    ...
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Please read [NGINX Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)! You will get back the invested time and a few days for free ;)

```
server { 
   server_name OLD.example.com;
   return 301 $scheme://example.com/NEW$request_uri;
}
```